# Javascript for loop with dynamic length

Tags: javascript, loops, conditional-statements

I have a piece of code to pull Twitter feed and it's working well, but sometimes a post doesn't contain image. I would like to get `settings.count` amount of posts to show, but I got less, because the lack of images.
How can I get the original amount of posts?

```
$.getJSON(settings.apiPath, { username: settings.username, list: settings.list, hashtag: settings.hashtag, count: settings.count, exclude_replies: settings.hideReplies }, function (twt) {
        that.find('span').fadeOut('fast', function () {
            that.html('<ul></ul>');

            for (var i = 0; i < settings.count; i++) {
                var tweet = false;
                if (twt[i]) {
                    tweet = twt[i];
                } else if (twt.statuses !== undefined && twt.statuses[i]) {
                    tweet = twt.statuses[i];
                } else {
                    break;
                }

                var temp_data = {
                    user_name: tweet.user.name,
                    date: dating(tweet.created_at),
                    tweet: (tweet.retweeted) ? linking('RT @' + tweet.user.screen_name + ': ' + tweet.retweeted_status.text) : linking(tweet.text),
                    avatar: '<img src="' + tweet.user.profile_image_url + '" />',
                    url: 'http://twitter.com/' + tweet.user.screen_name + '/status/' + tweet.id_str,
                    retweeted: tweet.retweeted,
                    screen_name: linking('@' + tweet.user.screen_name),
                    image: (tweet.entities.media) ? "<img src='" + tweet.entities.media[0].media_url + "' />" : false
                };

                that.find('ul').append('<li>' + templating(temp_data) + '</li>');
            }

            if (typeof callback === 'function') { callback(); }
        });
    });
```

I think somewhere should be an if statement with this: `typeof twt[i].entities.media != 'undefined'`

Comment: Did U tried to use twitter API ???

Comment: Yes, I tried. This is a custom approach. I think it doesn't matter if it's Twitter API or something else, I just try to find a way to exclude the posts without image. I was thinking maybe somehow I can increase/decrease it within the loop

Comment: Could U provide working example that could recreate problem (eg. working examle or git repo) and mocked data on which problem occurs ???